# Syntax error on token "<", invalid AssignmentOperator, in iterator.hasNext()

Tags: java

In iterator.hasNext(), it's showing an error.

Syntax error on token “<”, invalid AssignmentOperator, in iterator.hasNext()

```
 JSONArray build;
 int i;
    for (; iteratorData.hasNext(); i < build.length())
    {
      -------------
      -------------
      i++;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You put a condition in the increment/decrement clause of the for loop.

You probably meant to put it in the condition clause:

```
int i = 0;
for (; iteratorData.hasNext() && i < build.length(); )
{
    -------------
    -------------
    i++;
}
```

or even better:

```
int i = 0;
for (; iteratorData.hasNext() && i < build.length(); i++)
{
    -------------
    -------------
}
```

or (if you don't need to use the final value of `i` outside the loop):

```
for (int i = 0; iteratorData.hasNext() && i < build.length(); i++)
{
    -------------
    -------------
}
```

Comment: I have updated the question...Can you plzz look itnto it

Comment: @Geeky perhaps `JSONArray` doesn't have a `length()` method. Try `size()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is wrong for this basic `for` statement, according to the [JLS § 14.14](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14):

> ```
> BasicForStatement:
>   for ( [ForInit] ; [Expression] ; [ForUpdate] ) Statement
>
> BasicForStatementNoShortIf:
>   for ( [ForInit] ; [Expression] ; [ForUpdate] ) StatementNoShortIf
>
> ForInit:
>   StatementExpressionList 
>   LocalVariableDeclaration
>
> ForUpdate:
>   StatementExpressionList
>
> StatementExpressionList:
>   StatementExpression {, StatementExpression}
> ```

The third element of the basic `for` statement, that is, the one after the second semicolon, is referred to as 'ForUpdate' in the JLS. The ForUpdate requires a *[statement expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-StatementExpression)*, and `i < build.length()` is not a statement expression.

Since you're incrementing `i` at the end of each iteration, you can use that statement as ForUpdate statement:

```
for (...; ...; i++) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to do? But I think what you are trying to do is:

```
while(iteratorData.hasNext()) {
    for (int i = 0; i < build.length(); i++)
    {
      -------------
      -------------
      i++;
    }
}
```